# What is the formula for a normal-theory confidence interval of the mean?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, t-distribution

> A psychologist is collecting data on the time it takes to learn a certain task. For $55$ randomly selected adult subjects, the sample mean is $10.5$ minutes and sample standard deviation is $3.25$ minutes. Construct a $99\%$ confidence interval for the mean time required by all adults to learn the task.
>
> a. What formula to use.
> b. Plug all values in.

I think I should use a $t$-test formula which would be $(\bar x- \mu_0 )/(s/\sqrt n)$, so plugging in the values would be $(10.5-?)/(3.25/\sqrt{55})$.
What is the $\mu_0$ value? Am I right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Theoretical_example

Answer (score 2):

*(Since this question is so old, I suspect it is safe to provide an answer.)*

I think you're halfway there.  We might often use a $t$-test in a situation like this, but a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) is not quite the same thing as a [test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section1/prc13.htm).  Since the mean and SD are estimated from the data, you need to take that fact into account.  Thus, we will use the [$t$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) to form the confidence interval.  The general formula would be:
$$
\bar x \pm t_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\!,\ df)}\ \frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}
$$
The key to using this formula is to find the relevant $t$-value.  First, we need to get the df—it is $N-1=54$.  Then we look up the quantile that corresponds to the $99.5^{\rm th}$ percentile of that particular $t$-distribution in a [$t$-table](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/t-distribution-critical-value-table.php).  I find the value $2.67$.  Hence,
$$
10.5 \pm 2.67\ \frac{3.25}{\sqrt{55}} = 10.5 \pm 1.17 \Rightarrow (9.33,\ 11.67)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start saying you can use [this tool](https://www.mccallum-layton.co.uk/tools/statistic-calculators/confidence-interval-for-mean-calculator/#confidence-interval-for-mean-calculator) to check whether you answer is correct or not.

You should get a confidence interval of $\pm 1.13$.

That said, the correct formula to use is:

$$\bar x \pm z \frac{s}{\sqrt n}$$

Where the $\bar x$ is your average, the $z$ is a constant, $s$ is the standard deviation and $n$ is your sample size. The $z$ varies depending on the confidence interval you are trying to calculate. In your case, because 99%, $z$ is equal to $2.58$.

Plug all the numbers in the equation and you should get `1.130633169350857` which rounded gives you the $\pm 1.13$ I mentioned before. And that's it.

Comment: It is strange to read a pair of sentences in which the first claims "$z$ is a constant" and the second describes how "$z$ varies."  It would be hard for both to be true simultaneously!  Could you be more explicit about what $z$ represents, what it depends on, and how it is calculated?

Comment: I just want to add one more: the constant should not be 2.58. It is 2.58 if the sample size is large. And 55 is not large, we should probably use $t_{\alpha/2}$ instead.

Comment: Hi @whuber, interesting question. I checked different books and 'z' is often referred to as a constant so it is not a terminology I introduced. Now that you had me think about it, I believe the term coefficient should be used instead as more appropriate.

Comment: Hi @Penguin_Knight do you have any sources for this? The material I have does not make any distinction in terms of sample size. See, for example, this table: http://www.utdallas.edu/dept/abp/zscoretable.pdf

Comment: @AnnoysParrot, check t-table. z-table does not have degrees of freedom but t-distribution does. [Here](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/tools/stats/ttable.html) is a general table. And [here](http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=10) is an online calculator. If you punch in df of 1000 and alpha of 0.01, it'd be your answer 2.58; it's because t-distribution approaches normal distribution when df is high. But since the n is only 55, the df is now 54, yielding a 2.67. Also refer to Wikipedia page on "Student's t-distribution."

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Just thought I would mention that a lot of introductory stats courses, in my experience, use $n = 30$ as the cut off between $t$ and $Z$, so the instructor in this case could have been trying to get OP to use $Z$ depending on how they were taught.

Comment: @ChrisC, thank you. Your comment was well taken. Regards.